# magento soap api v2 catalogProductInfo not working

Tags: magento, soap, magento-1.7

When i call the api function as follows

`<?php $result = $client->catalogProductInfo($session, $id, null, 'sku'); ?>`

I get the following error. I'm positive that all the passed variables are set correctly, as other magento api functions work just fine.

Product not exists
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

I'm assuming that it's a fault with the call syntax. I couldn't find a proper example of calling *catalogProductInfo* with  sku instead of product id. 
The documentation http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html suggests to me that my call is correct.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to submit a space as last character of your SKU.
e.g. if SKU is `"1234"` submit `"1234 "`.

This issue sometimes occurs, if your submitted sku only contains numbers.

Comment: 8 hours of searching the dark web and finally this answer came up. I want to hug you

Answer (score 1):

I think you hit on a problem with the optional arguments which your call can take. `catalogProductInfo()` can take five arguments, of which the first one is the `sessionId`; all the other arguments are passed to the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2::info()`, which takes them as follows:

`public function info($productId, $store = null, $attributes = null, $identifierType = null)`

As you can see, just the `$productId` is obligatory, the other arguments are optional. But, if you want to pass the `$identifierType` argument to the method, you have to pass as well all the other arguments. So, in your case, you omit one of the `$store` or `$attributes` arguments, and the method takes your `sku` as the `$attributes` argument. That produces your error.

So you either should pass the missing argument, or you can just omit the `$identifierType` argument. Magento can guess from the input at `$productId` which identifier type you pass (product ID or sku). The `info()` method calls the `_getProduct()` method, which in turn calls `Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($productId, $this->_getStoreId($store), $identifierType)`. In this method Magento takes a guess about your `$productId` argument:

```
if ($identifierType === null) {
        if (is_string($productId) && !preg_match("/^[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*$|^0$/", $productId)) {
            $expectedIdType = 'sku';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing `$result = $client->catalogProductInfo($session, $id." ");` as you suggested. Now when I use the [link](http://<myshop>/checkout/cart/), the cart appears empty. I'm guessing that my cart id needs to be passed or smtg?

Comment: Don't know why you pass `$id." "` ? And: your API call is for the catalog, not for the cart, you shouldn't mix this up

Answer (score 0):

You left out the 4. param.

Function is smth. like this:

```
public catalogProductReturnEntity catalogProductInfo(
string sessionId,
string product,
string storeView,
**catalogProductRequestAttributes attributes,**
string productIdentifierType)
```

As "attributes" you passed "sku".