# magento soap api v2 catalogProductInfo "product not exists" error

Tags: xml, http, magento, soap

I've run in to the somewhat famous "product not exists" error when trying to get product information from magento using the v2 API. However, none of the usual remedies seem to work. For instance, I checked this thread: [magento soap api v2 catalogProductInfo not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749774/magento-soap-api-v2-catalogproductinfo-not-working)

Here is my request data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:catalogProductInfo>
      <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">291b294f0a5ec652069dfbd2ba1f42a3</sessionId>
      <productId xsi:type="xsd:string">917</productId>
    </ns1:catalogProductInfo>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Verified and regenereted the session id
- Full access for user
- Multiple product ID's (verified to exist, both in admin and using catalogProductList)
- Using both ID and SKU
- SKU's with a space behind it
- Adding <storeView> parameter
- Adding <productIdentifierType> parameter
- Combinations of the above

What's next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution: it turns out that the magento documentation on http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html is wrong. The parameter "productId" is actually called "product". So my working code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:catalogProductInfo>
      <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">291b294f0a5ec652069dfbd2ba1f42a3</sessionId>
      <product xsi:type="xsd:string">917</product>
    </ns1:catalogProductInfo>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Where do I report errors in the documentation?

Comment: ... and now I notice that it is also described as "product" in the wsdl. Evenso, the documentation should be corrected.

Answer (score 2):

I am accessing a magento API using C# and SOAP.

I had this same problem (**Product not exists**) and the solution for me was to **leave the last parameter `productIdentifierType` as `null` or `""`.**

```
details = service.catalogProductInfo(sessionId, prod.sku, null, null, "");
```

or

```
details = service.catalogProductInfo(sessionId, prod.product_id, null, null, "");
```

The documentation seems to say you should put "sku" or "product_id" (or "product" as I have seen others say), but this did not work for me.

You can use either the `sku` or the `product_id` as your second argument.

The space after the sku (as others have suggested) was not necessary.

Comment: I upvote only to thank you for mentionning that I could add a space after the SKU. This solved my problem.

Comment: Ultimately, it's a combination of adding a space at the end of the SKU and passing empty string "" to the last parameter for it to work for me.

Passing "sku" to the last parameter does not work at all (even with adding a space to the end of the SKU value.

Here's the snippet of code I used (Python using suds-jurko module, yes its embarassing to be using SOAP in 2018, but whatever): `product = client.service.catalogProductInfo(session, id_or_sku, None, attrib, "")`   `id_or_sku` is my sku, `attrib` is a `catalogProductRequestAttributes` obj created with `client.factory.create()`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in my case it was due to an update of Magento from 1.7 to 1.9. They changed the WSDL for catalogProductInfo (among other changes). I access the API with auto-generated C# code, and I had to update it (in Visual Studio: right click on the API and "Update Service Reference").

(this wouldn't normally be worth an answer, excepted when you're not notified of the server upgrade, you can search for quite a while before understanding what happened, so I hope this can help someone else)